# How to use Lookup formula for new rows in Google Sheets submitted via Google Form?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am using the following Lookup formula in a Google Sheet: `=LOOKUP(F2, AreaCodes)`

I need that formula to be triggered when new rows are added via a Google Form.

I'm guessing the solution has something to do with ArrayFormula but when I try using `=ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(F2, AreaCodes))` the values are not retrieved as new rows are added.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask] and more details to be able to reproduce the problem (i.e describe what is `AreaCodes`). Also it could be a good idea to add a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a formula `=LOOKUP(F2, AreaCodes)` and you want this to be updated as each Form Response is received.

You are using a named range (`AreaCodes`) as the search_result_array. When the range was created there were two options for establishing the range:

1 - Assign a starting row and an ending row (a fixed range). For example, the range might be "A2:B10". In this case, any new rows created by Form responses will fall outside the Named Range and will not be taken into account for the value of the formula.

2 - Assign a starting row, but do **not** assign an ending row (a pseudo-dynamic range). When this happens, the last row is assigned as the ending row. So, for example, the range might become "A2:B999".In this case, any new rows will fall within the named range and will influence the result of the formula.

**Diagnose and fix your problem**

If new Form Responses are not being updated by your existing formula, it means that the range applying to the Named Range is fixed.

To fix the problem: edit the Named Range, do not enter a closing row number and let the system automatically assign the last row as the ending number.